# HTTP Post request using Python 3

Tags: python, json, post, python-requests

So I'm trying to send a HTTP post request

```
>import requests
>
>data = {'cui':   '1234', 'data': '2015-02-14'}
>
>r = requests.post("https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/PlatitorTvaRest/api/v3/ws/tva", json={"cui":   '1234', "data": '2015-02-14'})
>
>print(r.status_code)
```

But I keep getting error code 500
The request works when using 3rd parties.

Request is sent to the link: "https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/PlatitorTvaRest/api/v3/ws/tva"

Header:Content-Type: application/json

Post Body is given:

Post Body:

```
[
    {           
       "cui": _Number_, "data":"_Date_"         
    },          
    {               
       "cui": _Number_, "data":"_Date_" 
    }       
]
```

Request example and response:
https://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Anaf/Informatii_R/documentatie_SW_01112017.txt

Comment: You could just do `json=data` instead of `json={"cui":   '1234', "data": '2015-02-14'}` because you have already initialized the `data` variable with the same `dictionary`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says the endpoint is expecting a *list* of dictionaries in that format, not a single dictionary. This works:

```
requests.post("https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/PlatitorTvaRest/api/v3/ws/tva", json=[{"cui": '1234', "data": '2015-02-14'}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer and I found your hints. Please find entire working code:

```
# EN: Romania - Split VAT register query
# RO: Romania - Registru plata TVA defalcata
import requests
import json
import timeit

# https://www.anaf.ro/anaf/internet/ANAF/informatii_publice/informatii_agenti_economici/RegPlataDefalcataTVA
# url = "https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/AsynchWebService/api/v3/ws/tva"
url = "https://webservicesp.anaf.ro/PlatitorTvaRest/api/v3/ws/tva"

# You may add here load data for CSV

# You may add here loop over data
#http://www.bvb.ro/FinancialInstruments/Details/FinancialInstrumentsDetails.aspx?s=snn
# data= [{"cui": '10874881', "data": '2017-12-14'}]
cui = '10874881'
date = '2017-12-14'
data_dict = {'cui': cui, 'data': date}
data = []
data.append(data_dict)

start = timeit.default_timer()
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
#print(r.text) # If you want to view entire content

key_start = r.text.find('[')
key_start+=1
key_end = r.text.find(']')

r_dict = r.text[key_start:key_end]
r_dict = json.loads(r_dict)
stop = timeit.default_timer()

print("status_code:", r.status_code)
print("data:", data) 
print("denumire:",r_dict['denumire'])
print("cui:", r_dict['cui'])
print("dataInceputSplitTVA:",r_dict['dataInceputSplitTVA'])
print("dataAnulareSplitTVA:", r_dict['dataAnulareSplitTVA'])
print("statusSplitTVA:",r_dict['statusSplitTVA'])
print("request duration:", stop - start) 

# You may add here save results to CSV

# Warning in Romanian language
# b) Orice tentativa de suprasolicitare a serverului va fi pedepsita conform reglementarilor in vigoare.
# Warning in English language
# b) Any attempt to overload the server will be punished according to the regulations in force.
#
# Results:
# status_code: 200
# data: [{'cui': '10874881', 'data': '2017-12-14'}]
# denumire: SOCIETATEA NATIONALA "NUCLEARELECTRICA" SA
# cui: 10874881
# dataInceputSplitTVA: 2017-09-29
# dataAnulareSplitTVA:  
# statusSplitTVA: True
# request duration: 0.18321414984132353

# Rough estimation of duration for request part only for 10000 records = 1832.141498 seconds
```

Comment: Please find below complete code and instructions for querying VAT split status using a list in CSV format.

https://github.com/itsergiu/Romania-split-VAT-register-query